# CSS Grid not applying on media queries

Tags: css, grid, media-queries

I don't know why grid values are not applying on settled @media 992 breakpoint on different _large.scss file, I think I'm using scss and @use correctly beacuse other properties are reacting properly on that breakpoint. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSnpN.jpg)

I have  line in html like someone asked

In addition when I unmark grid values from main.scss values are changing like I wanted.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSfsb.jpg)

Comment: Please do not include images of code. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557

Answer (score 0):

It's not because of Sass or @use, You should set the **display** of the parent as the **grid** to grid-row or grid-column works on child elements.
In your case, .header should be set `display: grid`

### Update

I reviewed this again, It's just a priority problem, Try it with !important in @media properties, or addressed it more specified (Ex. : use 'body' before .header to give it more priority in @media codes.

Comment: It didnt work, I tired this before